# Does clisp support thread?

Tags: clisp

I want to run hunchentoot using clisp. In clisp's REPL, i cannot do anything if hunchentoot is started.     It seems clisp doesnot support thread.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CLISP documentation on threads](http://clisp.org/impnotes/mt.html)

- you have to build CLISP with compile-time flag `--with-threads`
- this is experimental

Comment: It has been experimental for a long time :)